# Rotating Multi-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array

So I want to compare one 2-dimensional array with another 2-dimensional array (acctually portion of another larger 2-dimensional arrays). What I need to do is to compare the first array with the second, but I also need to compare it from multiple angles, rotating one of them if you will.

I'm writing this in c++ and I'm using vectors (in case there is a specific algorithm or function for these that would help)

Here's an example of what I need to be able to do with this:

```
Take this map:

0001000
0001000
0001000
0001111
0000000

Compare it to this (which means if 1 is road and 0 is grass, this would help 
me find 'turns' in the road):

010
110
000

Comparing it like that won't yield any results, BUT, if I rotate it to 180
degrees:

010
011
000

It fits.
```

More specifally I will compare a whole bunch of small arrays to the large array. I will not compare every location on the large array, only pick a location at random and a small array at random, rotate the small array to all 4 sides and see if they match. I will repeat this a few hundred times to find a decent sample of locations where a random selected sample of small maps compare positively to the large map.

Basically... :)

Atm I'm trying to figure it out, but I don't want to reinvent a wheel if I can help it.

(UPDATE: Close to solving this! I realised that I acctually need to rotate the lesser grid 8 times, I need to match every mirror! 
UPDATE2: lol I solved it wtf. Will post as soon as I understand what the code acctually does, might as well. 5 AM I'm crazy like this!)

Comment: Pretty good question.  The tag is odd, though.

Comment: just out of curiosity: what is this for? what is the software as a whole doing?

Comment: It's for my game engine. It's for creating random dungeons. I have a path that's randomly generated from multiple points. I then want to create 'locations' from the pattern in this path. I basically want a random dungeon with meaningful quests, which I believe I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Lol. Interesting problem. I want to try it too. Try reading into rotation matrices. They're a little straightforward when it comes to rotating the entire matrices, and if the angle of rotation greatly concerns you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: I only need 0, 90, 180, 270, 360 angles thank god! I'll read into it later thanks for the tip ;P